# Write a query in Oracle to obtain all rows that meet a condition based on resulting data

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to write an Oracle query that gives me all pipeline rows with multiple npd values. This is best illustrated through an example. I successfully write a query that relates pipeline name to npd as shown below.

```
select it.itemname, pr.npd
from rtrprdb.jpipelinesystem pl join
     rtrprdb.jnameditem it on it.oid = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.xsystemhierarchy x on x.oidorigin = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.jrtepiperun pr on pr.oid = x.oiddestination
order by it.itemname desc;
```

The first five rows of this query give the following result:

```
W-9244  1.5
W-9244  1.5
W-9244  1.5
W-9243  2.0
W-9243  1.5
```

These rows showing pipelines W-9244 and W-9243 may well be used to illustrate my intention. I would like to select pipelines with more than one distinct value for npd. For instance I would like to select W-9243 since it has two npd values of 2.0 and 1.5. On the other hand, I am not interested in selecting W-9244 because it only has one npd value of 1.5.

I tried to modify the query as shown below but was not successful:

```
select it.itemname, pr.npd
from rtrprdb.jpipelinesystem pl join
     rtrprdb.jnameditem it on it.oid = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.xsystemhierarchy x on x.oidorigin = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.jrtepiperun pr on pr.oid = x.oiddestination
group by it.itemname, pr.npd
having count(*) > 1
order by it.itemname desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the names and not the `npd` values:

```
select it.itemname
from rtrprdb.jpipelinesystem pl join
     rtrprdb.jnameditem it
     on it.oid = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.xsystemhierarchy x
     on x.oidorigin = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.jrtepiperun pr 
     on pr.oid = x.oiddestination
group by it.itemname
having count(distinct pr.npd) > 1
order by it.itemname desc;
```

If you want to include the values, you can do so as a string:

```
select it.itemname,
       listagg(pr.npd, ',') within group (order by pr.npd)
```

Finally, if you really want the original rows:

```
select itemname, npd
from (select it.itemname, pr.npd, count(*) over (partition by it.itemname) as cnt
      from rtrprdb.jpipelinesystem pl join
           rtrprdb.jnameditem it
           on it.oid = pl.oid join
           rtrprdb.xsystemhierarchy x
           on x.oidorigin = pl.oid join
           rtrprdb.jrtepiperun pr 
           on pr.oid = x.oiddestination
      group by it.itemname, pr.npd
     ) ip
where cnt > 1
order by it.itemname desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using distinct within the count function

```
select it.itemname, pr.npd
from rtrprdb.jpipelinesystem pl join
     rtrprdb.jnameditem it on it.oid = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.xsystemhierarchy x on x.oidorigin = pl.oid join
     rtrprdb.jrtepiperun pr on pr.oid = x.oiddestination
group by it.itemname, pr.npd
having count(distinct npd) > 1
order by it.itemname desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure from your question if you want just the distinct ITEMNAME values which are associated with multiple NPD values; if you want the distinct combinations of ITEMNAME and NPD where the ITEMNAME has multiple NPD values; or if you want all of the NPD values for each ITEMNAME which has multiple NPD values. So let's do them all:

To get the distinct ITEMNAMEs which are associated with multiple NPD values you can use:

```
WITH cteBase_data AS
       (SELECT it.ITEMNAME, pr.NPD
          FROM RTRPRDB.JPIPELINESYSTEM pl
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.JNAMEDITEM it
            ON it.OID = pl.OID
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.XSYSTEMHIERARCHY x
            ON x.OIDORIGIN = pl.OID
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.JRTEPIPERUN pr
            ON pr.OID = x.OIDDESTINATION),
     cteItems_of_interest AS
       (SELECT ITEMNAME
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME, NPD
                  FROM cteBase_data)
          GROUP BY ITEMNAME
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT ii.ITEMNAME
  FROM cteItems_of_interest ii
  ORDER BY ii.ITEMNAME
```

To get the distinct combinations of ITEMNAME and NPD for all ITEMNAMEs with multiple NPD values you can use:

```
WITH cteBase_data AS
       (SELECT it.ITEMNAME, pr.NPD
          FROM RTRPRDB.JPIPELINESYSTEM pl
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.JNAMEDITEM it
            ON it.OID = pl.OID
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.XSYSTEMHIERARCHY x
            ON x.OIDORIGIN = pl.OID
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.JRTEPIPERUN pr
            ON pr.OID = x.OIDDESTINATION),
     cteItems_of_interest AS
       (SELECT ITEMNAME
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME, NPD
                  FROM cteBase_data)
          GROUP BY ITEMNAME
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT DISTINCT bd.ITEMNAME, bd.NPD
  FROM cteBase_data bd
  INNER JOIN cteItems_of_interest ii
    ON ii.ITEMNAME = bd.ITEMNAME
  ORDER BY ITEMNAME, NPD
```

And to get all the rows where an ITEMNAME is associated with multiple NPD values you can use:

```
WITH cteBase_data AS
       (SELECT it.ITEMNAME, pr.NPD
          FROM RTRPRDB.JPIPELINESYSTEM pl
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.JNAMEDITEM it
            ON it.OID = pl.OID
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.XSYSTEMHIERARCHY x
            ON x.OIDORIGIN = pl.OID
          INNER JOIN RTRPRDB.JRTEPIPERUN pr
            ON pr.OID = x.OIDDESTINATION),
     cteItems_of_interest AS
       (SELECT ITEMNAME
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNAME, NPD
                  FROM cteBase_data)
          GROUP BY ITEMNAME
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT bd.ITEMNAME, bd.NPD
  FROM cteBase_data bd
  INNER JOIN cteItems_of_interest ii
    ON ii.ITEMNAME = bd.ITEMNAME
  ORDER BY ITEMNAME, NPD
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b85d245b825c509b50efa9826d9f522)